# Convert a string a DateTime with yyyyMMdd formatting

Tags: c#, datetime

I am not sure why this won't work. Can someone offer some advice?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string date = "11/17/2016";
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `date` is a `string` and not a `DateTime`. If you want to change the format you should parse that `string` to a `DateTime` and then convert it back to a `string` with the desired format.

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

Comment: @HughVeal I updated it to add the `, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, do you have that part?

Comment: I tried to use it this way, but it still gives me an error                                         'code' var drlobj = new Temp()
                {
                    Identity = values[0],
                    UnityPriceValue = decimal.Parse(values[4]) * -1,
                    Counterparty = values[7],
                    Maturity = DateTime.ParseExact(values[12], "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
                };'code'

Comment: @HughVeal What's the error?  What's the exact value of `values[12]` if it's not in the "MM/dd/yyyy" format then it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this:

```
string s = "11/17/2016";
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(s);
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```